# How does the multi-input deep learning work?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I have a multi-input convolutional neural network model that inputs 2 images from 2 datasets to give one output which is the class of the two inputs. The two datasets have the same classes.
I used 2 vgg16 models and concatenate them to classify the two images.

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
input_layer1= vgg16_model .input
last_layer1 = vgg16_model.get_layer('fc2').output


vgg16_model2 = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
input_layer2= vgg16_model .input
last_layer2 = vgg16_model.get_layer('fc2').output


con = concatenate([last_layer1, last_layer2])  # merge the outputs of the two models
output_layer = Dense(no_classes, activation='softmax', name='prediction')(con)
multimodal_model1 = Model(inputs=[input_layer1, input_layer2], outputs=[output_layer])
```

My questions are:

1- Which case from the following represents how the images enter to the model?

- One to One

  database1-img1 + database2-img1

  database1-img2 + database2-img2

  database1-img3 + database2-img3

  database1-img4 + database2-img4

  .........
- Many to many

  database1-img1 + database2-img1

  database1-img1 + database2-img2

  database1-img1 + database2-img3

  database1-img1 + database2-img4

  database1-img2 + database2-img1

  database1-img2 + database2-img2

  database1-img2 + database2-img3

  database1-img2 + database2-img4

  .........

2- In general in deep learning, Does the images enter from the two datasets to the model at the same time have the same class (labels) or not?

Comment: Rephrase your question and add a bit more detail for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: I rephrased the question. I have no more details I am asking in general how the images enters to the multi inputs deep learning model.

Comment: The model sounds interesting, but as far as I understand, the answer will depend on what you're asking what your model to predict. What do you need, or have the data for? Do you have a label for each of the image combinations (in either of the two cases)? Is it unsupervised? What labels do you have? Could both cases make sense for your data? You're second question is something only you can answer... unless you can share the data or give a lot more details.

Comment: @thanatoz   I have edited the question. I hope it is clear now.  Th second question is a general question, in multi model deep learning, does the entered inputs at the same time have same labels or no???